# How to make width of navigation auto, while absolutely positioning its wrapper

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS:

```
    <style>

ul, ol, dl {    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

         #navWrapper {
            background:#3C6;
            height: 90px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            width: 600px;
        }


        #nav {
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            }

        #nav li {
            float: left;
            list-style-type: none;
            }

        #nav li a, #nav a:visited {
            display: block;
            padding: 8px 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #069;
            border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }

        #nav li a:hover, #nav a:active, #nav a:focus {
            color: #c00;
            background-color: #fff; }

    .clearfloat { 
        clear:both;
        height:0;
        font-size: 1px;
        line-height: 0px;
    }

    #wrapper {
        width: 965px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    a img { 
        border: none;
        float: left;
    }



    </style>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="" alt="Insert Logo Here" name="Insert_logo" width="300px" height="90px" id="Insert_logo"/></a> 
   <div id="navWrapper">
   <div id="nav">
      <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
    </ul>
  <!-- end #nav --></div>
  <!-- end #navWrapper --></div>
    <!-- end .header --></div>
    <div class="clearfloat"></div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to create a navigation bar that sits on the bottom of its wrapper. The only way I can think to do this is using absolute positioning and setting the bottom to 0. But the problem is I have to set a width the div inside of the wrapper, which is what my code reflects now. I want the width to be dynamic and change with the width of the navigation bar while it still sits on the bottom of the wrapper, aligned to the bottom of the header image. How can I do this?

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fCEn/)

Comment: I didn't post all my code. Its all there now. Please try again. I can't have anything dropping below anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `#nav` to 100% width, and the four items to 25% width each.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fCEn/2/)

If you mean something else, leave a comment.

---

Here are the exact changes I made.

```
#nav {
   width: 100%; /* Add: */ 
}

#nav li {
   width: 25%; /* Add: */ 
}
```

---

Based on the fiddle [you provided](http://jsfiddle.net/3fCEn/7/), the left float on the navWrapper is causing problems.  Removing it hides the logo, which is floated left.  To fix this, put a clearfix before the navWrapper, and after the logo image.

### [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fCEn/9/)

Comment: that didn't work at all. You would have to look at my code and tell me the proper place to put the width's.

Comment: Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fCEn/4/) with your updated code.  I guess I don't know what you're looking for...

Comment: I already did that. If you put that in the code, you will see it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh i see, it's working on the code I gave you but when I put it in my full site, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: see here is the updated fiddle... look what it is doing when I add only your code... http://jsfiddle.net/3fCEn/7/

Comment: the logo is sitting above the navigation. I don't want this. I need the logo to be to the left of the nav

Comment: How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3fCEn/11/)?  I went element by element in FireBug to find what broke it... somehow `width: 600px;` got lost.  I added it and now it seems to work.

Comment: No, because when I add two more links, the links start to stack on one another, and when I extend the length of a link name the format is broken. I need the nav bar to be flexible, I'm still not getting this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5970/discussion-between-fakerainbrigand-and-michael-rader)